# Antisamy removing string after script tag

Tags: java, owasp, antisamy

I have a scenario where i pass a string through AntiSamy tag. The string is  .

```
String dirtyContent = "<script>test<script>testing";
CleanResults cr = as.scan(dirtyContent, policy);
System.out.println(cr.getCleanHTML());
```

So i am expecting AntiSamy to remove the  tag and its content and print  testing. But AntiSamy is removing the entire content and return empty string. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an error that i recognized later. The script tag was not properly closed. `<script>test<script>testing` should have been `<script>test</script>testing`
So internally what antisamy was doing is making `<script>test<script>testing` as `<script>test<script>testing</script>` and then removing the whole string. Caught this finally. Thanks for the help.